# extract url from text with www - PHP

Tags: php

I need to examine a text to extract the urls in case it contains them.
As far as I have been able to find out there is this function that does it.

```
preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $string, $match);
```

The problem is that this function only extracts urls if they start with http .

How can I make it extract urls that start with www.xxx as well?

Comment: I suspect not everything with the format `www.xxx` can be considered as a URL. It at least needs to start with `http://`.

Comment: I think the answer to your question is `(?:https?://)?)`. That makes the protocol optional. I don't know though if that will give you what you want. The protocol is the only really identifiable way of finding links. A subdomain can be numerous things (and also is optional).

Comment: What about all root domains? LIke `example.com`? How would you get that as a link? Far from all URL's/root domains have a `www` sub domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex expression to identify URLS that use www. https and http.

```
$url = "www.example.com";

if (preg_match_all("^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$^", $url)) {
    echo "URL is valid";
} else {
    echo "URL is invalid";
}
```